# python read 2 files, ignore header (# beginning line), and sort data

Tags: python, sorting, startswith

How can I read two file at once, ignoring # lines, and sort them with their 2nd column values?

I was thinking of combination of .startswith(): and sorted(): command

```
    file1 = [line for line in open("file1.txt",'r').readlines() if not line.startswith("#")]
    file2 = [line for line in open("file2.txt",'r').readlines() if not line.startswith("#")]

    sorted_file1 = sorted(file1, key=lambda line: int(line.split()[1])) 
    sorted_file2 = sorted(file2, key=lambda line: int(line.split()[1]))

    do something fun using sorted files with for and if
```

My files are very simple. file 1 have values like

```
AAA 15125
BBB 69121
CCC 366161
....
```

and file 2 looks like

```
bkjnwg 11111
knksng 22155
bnkiop 13511
...
```

But I feel something strange about this code. How can I read, ignore #, and sort files more simply?

Thanks

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited per comment.

You can do:

```
files_to_do = [...] #put paths in here
for f in files_to_do:
    lines = [line for line in open(f,'r').readlines() if not line.startswith("#")]
    sorted_lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: int(line.split()[1]))
    #party
```

Comment: Thank you Tommy. But I hope to analyze file 1 and file 2 separately. But your second suggestion (generalized approach for n number of files) is really great. Thanks

Comment: Answer edited; that was not clear from the question.